# How to get value from point(a b) swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have this kind of string: "`POINT(101.650577657408 3.1653186153213)`".

Anyone know how can I get the first and second value of `POINT` from this String?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily spit the string using `componentsSeparatedByString` function.

```
let myStr = "POINT(101.650577657408 3.1653186153213)"
let characterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "( )")
var splitString = myStr.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(characterSet)
print(splitString[0])
print(splitString[1])
print(splitString[2])
```

The above only works if you have the complete one String.

Comment: you missed "`POINT(`", thats a whole string i think.

Comment: @the_UB I don't think so, I hope its like this `String POINT = "101.650577657408 3.1653186153213"`. Let him confirm then!

Comment: Thanks you everyone let me try your answer

Comment: `POINT(101.650577657408 3.1653186153213)` is a whole string or `NSString *POINT = "101.650577657408 3.1653186153213"`?

Comment: @the_UB POINT(101.650577657408 3.1653186153213) is the whole string

Comment: @the_UB yes, regex will work, but I have edited answer with the better option. Please look at that!

Answer (score 1):

Although the `NSCharacterSet` solution is correct but here is another solution using the most powerful **regex**.

```
var error: NSError?

// Initialise the regex for a float value
let regex: NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\d*\\.\\d*)", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &error)! 

// Matches array contains all the match found for float in given string
let matches: NSArray = regex.matchesInString(str as String, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportProgress, range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length))

// You can easily get all values by enumeration
for match in matches {
    println(str.substringWithRange(match.range))
}
```

The benefit of this solution is it will scan all the float values and will also work in case of pattern got changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, this will work for your string**

```
    let myStr = "POINT(101.650577657408 3.1653186153213)"
    let strWithout_POINT_openingBrace = myStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("POINT(", withString: "")//"101.650577657408 3.1653186153213)"
    let strWithout_closingBrace = strWithout_POINT_openingBrace.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")//"101.650577657408 3.1653186153213"
    //now you have only space between two values
    //so split string by space
    let arrStringValues = strWithout_closingBrace.componentsSeparatedByString(" ");//["101.650577657408","3.1653186153213"]

    print(arrStringValues[0]);//first value "101.650577657408"
    print(arrStringValues[1]);//second value "3.1653186153213"
```